# What is GAE changing to my POST request?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm working with an external API that unfortunately doesn't have that great error logging.

I use django 1.9.5 and requests 2.11.1.

When I make the following request with the built-in python server (python manage.py runserver) on my local machine, I get back a 200 status code, so this works fine.

```
r = requests.post(
    'https://plazaapi.bol.com/offers/v1/%s' % product.ean, data=xml_to_send,
         headers=headers)
```

headers are a dictionary of the date, an authorization code and the content-type
.

But as there is a problem with requests on GAE according to other answers on this site, I have tried to use the requests_toolbelt monkeypatch and urlfetch, but I always get back the following error then:

> Request contains invalid authentication headers

Code with the monkeypatch:

```
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

r = requests.post(
     'https://plazaapi.bol.com/offers/v1/%s' % product.ean, data=xml_to_send,
      headers=headers)
```

and

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

r = urlfetch.fetch(
    url='https://plazaapi.bol.com/offers/v1/%s' % product.ean,
    payload=xml_to_send,
    method=urlfetch.POST,
    headers=headers,
    follow_redirects=False) # tried this, but has no effect.
```

The headers I'm setting are:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
           'X-BOL-Date': date,
           'X-BOL-Authorization': signature}
```

> **Is GAE changing my request and adding headers? If so, can I stop it
>   from doing so?**

Comment: Why don't you try the same request outside GAE to check it out? Same headers, same options, just try from your local machine and see what you get.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP I tried that, and it succeeded. I'll edit it to make it more clear

Comment: Yes, App Engine does modify headers.  This might be helpful:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#app-engine-specific-headers

Comment: Why not send the request to https://requestb.in/ and you'll see exactly what headers are being sent from GAE